# Does Network Link Conditioner Work Well on El Capitan

Tags: macos

I had Network Link Conditioner as part of Xcode 6.1 package & was working fine. I just upgraded my to OS X El Capitan. Should I replace my NLC to the one found in Xcode 7.3 or my existing NLC of Xcode 6.1 should still be performing fine?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, It will perform as expected.

Bear in mind that the *Network Link Conditioner* has noting to do with Xcode itself, but with the OS.

When downloading theses *Hardware tools* Apple points out that `these graphics tools support running on [OS]` which might lead you to think that and update is necessary, but the protocols and / or the way the *NLC* interacts with the System's connectivity, doesn't seem to have changed, as it does, indeed, work.